# Correct way of formatting dates for output in node theming

Tags: 7, datetime

I am theming a node where I need to show the created date. Since Drupal stores it as timestamp, what is the best method to retrieve it? I have found this post: http://drupal.org/node/101993. But the problem is that whe using this...

```
<?php 
print date("D, j M, Y \a\\t G:i", $node->changed);
?>
```

... it delivers me the content in English. My portal default language is Portuguese. Is there a Drupal function that will deliver the timestamp as a regular date that takes into account the user's selected language? And  that maybe takes into account the preformatted dates set in the portal configuration? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of date(), try using [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/7)

It has an otional last parameter `$langcode` that tells it what language code to use for the date.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I found the documentation here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/7